# how add unique column to table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, unique

I have table. And I have made an migration and set there `add_column :articles, :hash_code, :string, :unique => true`, bun it doesn't work.

Can you give me any help?

Answer (score 0):

According the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#active-record-and-referential-integrity)

> The Active Record way claims that intelligence belongs in your models, not in the database. As such, features such as triggers or foreign key constraints, which push some of that intelligence back into the database, are not heavily used.
>
> Validations such as validates :foreign_key, :uniqueness => true are one way in which models can enforce data integrity. The :dependent option on associations allows models to automatically destroy child objects when the parent is destroyed.

So all you need to do is validate uniqueness of the attribute in your model and this is it! And if you want to add the index too then that can be added in migration file itself.

Answer (score 0):

:unique => true belongs on the add_index statement instead of the add_column statement.

The add_index syntax is shown below:

add_index :table_name, :column_name, :unique => true

Comment: it must be in my model somethink like this `validates_uniqueness_of :hash_code` ?